# Custom testInstrumentationRunner only for specific tests

Tags: android, testing, junit

I have custom `testInstrumentationRunner` and I set it inside `gradle` this way:

```
`testInstrumentationRunner` `com.dom.androidtest.TestRunner`
```

But I want to run only specific tests with this `testInstrumentationRunner` and **I don't want to deliver my changes to `gradle`**. Is there a way to set my `TestRunner` for specific class, like `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` for `JUnitRunner`? Again the goal is to apply the runner not though `gradle` but inside the class itself.

Comment: @tir38 it is not as I specified I don't want to deliver my changes to gradle. And that questions and answers are specifically related how to do that though gradle